# how to sort array of NSDictionary

Tags: ios

i have array of NSDictionary like below

```
array(
        {
        Birthdate = "03/20";
        Names = "Abhinavswati Chaudhary";
        remain = 0;
    },
        {
        Birthdate = "09/22/1986";
        Names = "Aisa Soni";
        remain = 186;
    },
        {
        Birthdate = "03/02/1990";
        Names = "Anuj Parekh";
        remain = 347;
    },
        {
        Birthdate = "05/22/1988";
        Names = "Ajay Desai";
        remain = 63;
    }
)
```

how can i sort this array in ascending with accordance to remain
for example it should be like

```
 array(
       {
       birthdate=...
       name =abhivan
       remanin =0;
   },
      {
       brithdate = "05/22/1988";
       name =ajay
       remain =63
   },
      {
       and so on....
```

plz suggest some code thank you in advance

when we use NSsortDiscripor then remain need to be NSNumber, can it be the reason that my remain numbers are actually string ?

Comment: are you got the answer?

Comment: Sunny my brother let me try :)

Comment: array order get changed but not in ascending its just changed randomly

Comment: can it be the reason behind my problem that in remain that numbers are  NSString and not NSNUmber cus of that it may not be able to sort it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple by using the `sortedArrayUsingComparator` method of NSArray.
In your case it should look like:

```
yourArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    // get values
    NSNumber *remain1 = obj1[@"remain"];
    NSNumber *remain2 = obj2[@"remain"];

    return [remain1 compare:remain2];
}];
```

Comment: my array contain Dic so will it change all combined element of dic or it will change only remain?

Comment: it will change the dicts, sorted by "remain"